Why am I getting 'A call is in progress notification" even after doing hangup by following code?
I have created a one way webrtc sender for sending video/audio stream to receiver. I have placed constrains audio: true video: true for getUserMedia(). I am performing close media tracks and it shows verbose on console for closing but I cant get that notification away. I am not getting stream form receiver so there is no remoteStream to close.
Heres code:
static Future<void> hangUp() async {
    if (!parametersReady)
      throw '[WebrtcSender.hangUp] feedParameters was not called';
    print(
        '[WebrtcSender.hangup] hanging up for  receiver $receiverEmail sender $userEmail');

    try {
      if (localStream != null) {
        localStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) {
          track.stop();
        });
        localStream!.dispose();
      }
      if (peerConnection != null) {
        print('[WebrtcSender.haungUp] closing peerConnection');
        await peerConnection!.close();
      }
      FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      DocumentReference roomRef = db
          .collection('sessions')
          .doc(receiverEmail)
          .collection(userEmail)
          .doc('videoStream');

      DocumentSnapshot<Object?> roomSnapshot = await roomRef.get();

      if (roomSnapshot.exists) {
        var calleeCandidates =
            await roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').get();
        calleeCandidates.docs
            .forEach((document) => document.reference.delete());

        var callerCandidates =
            await roomRef.collection('callerCandidates').get();
        callerCandidates.docs
            .forEach((document) => document.reference.delete());
        answerSet = false;
        await roomRef.delete();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('[WebrtcSender.hangup] error ${e.toString()}');
      DebugFile.saveTextData('[WebrtcSender.hangup] error ${e.toString()}');
      rethrow;
    }
  }



